# WindowBackground PreferencActivity in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, background, preferenceactivity

i have setted the WindowBackground for my PreferenceActivity.

When i use 2.3.3 the background image gets displayed correct, but when i scroll the orginal theme comes to foreground. In my case white background.

My manifest file:

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity_Settings" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme"/>
```

my style:

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme">   
         <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/repeat</item> 
</style>
```

Can anyone give me a hint why the background changes to the orginal theme while iam scrolling?

Best regards 
Yannick

PS: With Android 4.0 all works fine.

EDIT: My @layout/repeat is:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/background"
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Comment: repeat is your layout placed in res/layout/?

Comment: Yes, i added my layout/repeat to the question.

Comment: i think repeat.xml should be inside `res/drawable` folder. can you try it after placing repeat.xml inside `res/drawable` folder?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tryed out, it doesn't work :/. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, make sure that you set the Cache Color Hint in the Activity'S onCreate methode:

```
 getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```